# How to pass jQuery variable using Ajax get request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, slider

I have a values generated by a jQuery slider. I need to pass its variable to a url in the form http://domain.com/index.php?rich=3&sweet=6. I need to use Ajax's get request to send the javascript variables (rich and sweet)  to the url.

I have the following javascript in my index.php file (the variables are assigned values set by the select/slider HTML code), selectToUISlider() couples the slider to a pulldown menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#rich').selectToUISlider({
labels:7, sliderOptions: {
stop: function(e,ui) {
  var richValue = $('#rich').val();    
  }}}).next();

$('#sweet').selectToUISlider({
labels:7, sliderOptions: {
stop: function(e,ui) {
  var sweetValue = $('#sweet').val();
  }}}).next();          

}
</script>
........
```

The HTML code below (I omitted the 'sweet' select code)

```
    <form action="index.php" name="form1" method="GET">
<!-- demo 1 -->
<fieldset>

        <select name="rich" id="rich" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <optgroup label="Not too Rich">
        <?php $rich1 .= '<option'.(isset($_GET['rich']) && $_GET['rich']=='1' ? ' selected ' : ' ').'value="1">'.'Not too Rich'.'</option>'."\n"; ?>
        <?php echo $rich1 ?>

          .........................

        <?php $rich7 .= '<option'.(isset($_GET['rich']) && $_GET['rich']=='7' ? ' selected ' : ' ').'value="7">'.'Super Rich'.'</option>'."\n"; ?>
        <?php echo $rich7 ?>

        </optgroup>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
```

My understanding is that I have to work this:

```
$.get('index.php?rich='+ $('#rich').val() , function(data) {
                            $('#rich').html(data);
                        });
```

into the code somehow but I don't know how.

Comment: that should work. Did u get any error? Are you trying to pass multiple form elements' values then this may help, http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ .

Comment: yes multiple values, I need to see how to piece everything including serialize together

Comment: Would you explain in brief what are you trying to do? Which slider library? Create a small working demo on jsfiddle.net which will explain your problem more accurately.

Comment: Just read your message. I found a fix. For #rich.selecttoslider: I read in the variables richValue and sweetValue, I used the get.() function, then I used window.location to set the parameters with the values of richValue and sweetValue. For #sweet.selecttoslider: I did the same thing but left out the get.().

Comment: The objective was to add parameters (e.g. ?rich=3&sweet=4) to the url using the jquery slider from the filament group. This allows me to read in the slider output into PHP and process it

Comment: $('#rich').selectToUISlider({
 labels:7,

  sliderOptions: {
    stop: function(event ,ui) {
var sweetValue = $('#sweet').val();
      var richValue = $('#rich').val();
 
   $.get('index.php', {rich : $('#rich').val()}, function(data) {
   

   window.location="http://www.resumeicons.com/test1/index.php?rich="+richValue+"&sweet="+sweetValue; 
 
});   
    
    }
  }
}).hide().next();

Comment: Wait...the iphone browser doesn't append the url with the parameter values

Answer (score 2):

Yeah but more suitable way is:

```
$.get('index.php', {rich : $('#rich :selected').val()}, function(data) {
    //so something with data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Denis Ermolin is right, but why "GET" request? Your will have problems in IE whith cashing - IE love to cahe urls sometimes. Use "POST" - IE will not cash it.

```
$.post('index.php', {rich : $('#rich :selected').val()}, function(data) {
    //so something with data
});
```

Comment: My comment was for question author ) Your variant is correct of course.

Comment: I thought GET would place the variables in the url and serve as a proxy/intermediary, which is a method for also using PHP to use the variables. The POST statement as posted doesn't change anything: http://www.resumeicons.com/test1/index.php . The url still doesn't change when the slider is moved

Comment: You have no code on slider move. You only have 1 call to $.get in main file. And it works good. I think you a bit confused with your code.

Comment: You have to read documentation on Jquery UI Slider. I don't remember. It has some event onChange. Read on official website.